# how to get details in list view from sqlite database in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I want display all details in a `ListView` from an SQLite database. How do I set a custom `Adapter` in `MainActivity`? My code is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText eid,ename;
    Button add;
    public DatabaseClass mdb=null;
    public Cursor c=null;
    public SQLiteDatabase db=null;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="Sample.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        eid=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.rid);
        ename=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.rname);
        add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.radd);        
        mdb=new DatabaseClass(getApplicationContext(), DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                db = mdb.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
                int id=Integer.parseInt(eid.getText().toString());
                String name=ename.getText().toString();

                cv.put("ID",id );
                cv.put("NAME",name );
                db.insert("DEMO", null, cv);

            }
        }); 

    }
}

database class

public class DatabaseClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DatabaseClass(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DEMO(ID INTEGER,NAME VARCHAR);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: actually this is not a code review forum, you must tell us **WHICH ONE** and **WHERE** is exactly your problem...

Comment: Search on google using *sql listview android example* . Tons of examples

Comment: _this is my sample code as given above, this program and database using how to display in list view data from list view that's my question?_

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this tutorial: [Android | Simple SQLite Database Tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

It helped me a lot! Just follow the whole tutorial!

Use the extra class to create/update/find/delete items to the database.
Don't do it in your Activity.

First things I see:

1. One semicolon to much in your create string.